# Is there a noun for "touch" or "move" when they mean "to stir one's emotions or feelings" in particular context (instead of other definition)?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have just been learning English for a short time, and I find a phenomenon that there tends to be a corresponding noun for every word related to emotion, such as "amaze" and "amazement", "impress" and "impression", or some words like "surprise" can be both used as a verb or a noun. Plus, it seems feasible to convey such kind of meaning either with the verb or with the noun, like "something impresses me" = "something leaves me a deep impression", "something surprises me" = "To my surprise".

However, I failed to find a noun for "moved/touched" when they have the emotion related meaning as in "something deeply moved/touched me". Maybe there should be another word with the meaning of "the feeling or state of being moved/touched", but when I think of their definition I often find it a little bit different from what I think that of the verb "move" or "touch". This really confused me because in my mother language there is an accurate noun to convey this kind of meaning. Could anyone help me with the problem?

Comment: You can describe the emotion itself. I am comforted. Something calmed me. Something relaxed me. Something thrilled/excited me.

Comment: Or you can use _feel_ or _feeling_ in its generic sense.

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence with a blank for the word showing how you’d like to use it?

Comment: How short is this "short time"? Even allowing for the editing that KillingTime did, your question is much better composed than average.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Do you mean the state of being affected by any emotion, regardless whether it's positive or negative? Or specific emotions? Warmth, sympathy, love, etc? Does *emotion* not work?

Answer (score 1):

***WordHippo*** has the option of searching for different parts of speech deriving from a certain word. The meaning your are looking for in the nouns ***move*** and ***touch*** *were* there, but are now obsolete:

> [move](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-noun-for/move.html):
>
> - (obsolete) Motion of the mind or feelings; ***emotion***.

> [touch](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-noun-for/touch.html):
>
> - (obsolete) Act or power of exciting ***emotion***.
> - (obsolete) An ***emotion*** or affection.

As you can see, the word *emotion* often comes out often in the definitions, and is indeed the closest to what you need, though not exactly, I know.

Note that ***emotion*** and ***move*** have [the same root](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=emotion). But to say what you want to say, you'll have to find other ways around it. You still have the adjectives ***[moving](https://www.google.com/search?q=moving%20meaning&oq=moving%20meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l9.7588j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)*** and ***[touching](https://www.google.com/search?q=touching%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsaWE7kGBl9gySx2J3Qf7iaxQ7Af8w%3A1660071353226&ei=ua3yYrqbDdK68gKx8LjADg&ved=0ahUKEwj6273at7r5AhVSnVwKHTE4DugQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=touching%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyEggAEIAEEIcCELEDEBQQRhD5ATIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzoHCAAQRxCwAzoHCAAQsAMQQzoHCAAQgAQQCjoHCCMQsAIQJzoECAAQDUoECEEYAEoECEYYAFDpB1iBGWCwG2gCcAF4AIABaogBsAWSAQM4LjGYAQCgAQHIAQrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)*** that have preserved this meaning and can be of help.

Answer (score 0):

In some circumstances you could use **agitation**. If moved or touched by events or thoughts you may be agitated and in a state of agitation.

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/agitation)
> *agitation*:
> emotional disturbance or excitement

Here is an example of such usage:

> [26 Power of Words](https://www.26.org.uk/articles/interviews/every-object-tells-story)
> "*Last week was dominated by the fire in Grenfell Tower. When I arrived at South Kensington station on Friday morning it was in my thoughts. I was agitated by arriving in South Kensington to look at and write about objects that are historical and beyond conventional judgements of price and value – and the contrast with North Kensington just up the road.*"

Here, the writer is emotionally touched and moved to write by the recollection of the (deaths in a fire) events at Grenfell Tower.

However, although this Collins definition fits your request quite generally, *agitation* tends to be used more when the emotions of anxiety, concern or distress are excited by adverse circumstance or unpleasant experience. So it should be used with care.

Here is Cambridge:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/agitation)
> *agitation*:
> worry and anxiety:
> *He arrived home in a state of agitation*